# JavaScript and Dealing with Floating Point Determinism

Tags: javascript, html, floating-point, point, multiplayer

I'm looking to build a browser multiplayer game using rollback netcode that runs a deterministic simulation on the clients. I prototyped the netcode in Flash already before I ran into the floating point roadblock.

Basically, from what I understand, integer math in Flash is done by casting `int`s to `Number`s, doing the math, then casting back to `int`. It's faster apparently, but it means that there's no chance of deterministic math across different computer architectures.

Before I dump all my eggs into the JavaScript basket then, I'd like to ask a few questions.

1. Is there true integer arithmetic on all major browsers in JavaScript? Or do some browsers do the Flash thing and cast to floats/doubles to do the math before casting back to int?
2. Does something like [`BigDecimal`](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js) or [`BigNum`](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) work for deterministic math across different computer architectures? I don't mind some performance loss as long as it's within reason. If not, is there some JavaScript fixed point library out there that solves my problem?
3. This is a long shot, but is there a HTML5 2D game engine that has deterministic math for stuff like x/y positions and collisions? The list of [game engines](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines) is overwhelming to say the least. I'm uneasy about building a deterministic cross browser compatible engine from scratch, but that might be what I have to do.

NOTE: Edited from HTML5 to JS as per responses. Apologies for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: The issue is not really about HTML5, it's about JavaScript.

Comment: Surely you mean accuracy, (to me) determinism has a very different meaning.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @Cristy I ended up working around it. In essence, I run a simulation on the server as the master copy, and when I detect that a client is out of sync with the master, I dump the game state to the desynced client.

Comment: @na Thank you for your response! I am trying to make it deterministic by converting all computations to integers and using look tables for trigonometric functions, but I don't know if this actually solves the solution and makes it deterministic.

Comment: @Cristy In my limited understanding, I had no way of proving if that was truly deterministic, so I instead assumed that it wasn't and worked with that assumption. I felt it safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Javascript issue - not an HTML5 one.

All Javascript math is done using IEEE754 floating point `double` values - there are no "ints".

Although IEEE754 requires (AFAIK) a specific answer for each operation for any given input, you should be aware that JS interpreters are potentially free to optimise expressions, loops, etc, such that the floating point operations don't actually execute in the order you expect.

Over the course of a program this *may* result in different answers being produced on different browsers.

Comment: For the browser then, is a deterministic simulation across different computer architectures impossible to do?

Comment: @na to be honest I think you just need to try it and see.